# How to prevent Knockout from overwriting my initial checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a form which loads normally through the browser and is populated with Laravel, but uses Knockout.js and AJAX to page updates to the server:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('launch_time_change', 'launch_time_change', true, array('data-bind' => checked: emailNotifications.launch_time_change')) }}
```

The third parameter here represents the state of the checkbox on page load, as you can see, it is checked.

However, I would like to then send this value through to Knockout so the checkbox can be updated on the server without a page reload. This necessitates storing the checkbox value in a `ko.observable()`, but whenever I try and apply the `checked` binding to my checkbox field, the default state is overwritten.

In the above case, a checkbox which was initially selected on page loads becomes unselected as Knockout initializes the observables in the ViewModel. This is the [expected behaviour](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html), sadly:

> KO sets the element’s checked state to match your parameter value. Any previous checked state will be overwritten.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: What control do you have over your knockout viewmodel?  Can you not just initialise the observable correctly?

Comment: If you can't directly set the observable correctly during the construction of the page, can you at least run some extra JS code that takes the value of the actual checkbox and sets the observable in the viewmodel before you call `applyBindings`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe, complete control, but I'm not willing to make a separate AJAX request to download the data too. I could initialize the observables before applyBindings, but I've never done it before so I have no idea how that would work.

Comment: Pass the checkbox value to the view model constructor and set it to the observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I chose to go an entirely different route for this, considering my application is predominantly Laravel-based.

I decided to use [Jeffrey Way's `laracasts/utilities` repo](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer) to create a `Javascript` facade where I could put Javascript variables onto my view like so:

```
    JavaScript::put([
        'emailSubscriptions' => someValue
    ]);
```

This is than accessible anywhere globally, in a namespaced variable attached to the `window` object:

```
console.log(laravel.emailSubscriptions) // "someValue"
```

It shouldn't pollute the global scope because under `config.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JavaScript Namespace
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, we'll add variables to the global window object.
| It's recommended that you change this to some namespace - anything.
| That way, from your JS, you may do something like `Laracasts.myVar`.
|
*/
'js_namespace' => 'laravel'
```

Works pretty nicely plus it's accessible anywhere, not just inline. No need to pass via a constructor or make a separate AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer using Knockout is to create a new `value` bind that does not overwrite the input value.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dont_clear_init_value = _.extend({},
  ko.bindingHandlers.value,
  {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
      if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor()))
        valueAccessor()(ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element));

      ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    }
  }
);
```

How to use in the template.

```
<p>Login name: <input data-bind="dont_clear_init_value: userName" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" data-bind="dont_clear_init_value: userPassword" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        userName: ko.observable(),
        userPassword: ko.observable(),
    };
</script>
```